# Checkbox's value disappear

Tags: html, checkbox

Checkbox's value disappear When I inspect element, I didn't see a value of my checkbox.

This is my code

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="test" value="hello">
```

and when I inspect element I get this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="test" value="">
```

(I don't know any jquery files kill it or not)

Comment: Post the full code then. Unable to help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect if you check-box has been `checked` you should use some JavaScript, below an example.

Regarding your `value` on the `checkbox` if you do not have any other code changing value, the value will remain on your HTML.

https://jsfiddle.net/d94w84q9/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="test" value="hello" checked>


var value = document.getElementById('test').checked;
alert(value)
```

Comment: Please also post your full code so we can have a look in more details.

Comment: Thank for your help. I found a jquey function to change value to "".
sorry for waste your time T T

Comment: @narunsa thanks for your comment, if you think my answer help you out, please upvote or accept it :)